# Symfony app/console command not responding - debugging ideas?

Tags: php, console

PHP has become unresponsive after installing PHPUnit by Pear to MAMP.

I don't get any error messages to app/logs, or MAMP php- or apache logs. 
I tried uninstalling the PHPUnit through PEAR, but no change.

Any ideas for debugging this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*has become unresponsive*". Does the process freeze or is it slow? What kind of command is it - could you add some code ?

Comment: Process just freezes (I let it run for a couple of minutes, so pretty well frozen). I updated the question, noticed it's actually the whole PHP that freezes.

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled? Some opcode cache in place like zend-opcode or apc ? Cleared the cache?

Comment: "The whole PHP that freezes", interesting... I suggest you make a trivial test script and check what is happening.

Comment: Bloody hell. Xdebug, forgot all about that, was so concentrated on terminal that I didn't notice phpStorm + xdebug on the background. That seemed to be the culprit... Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 6):

The answer was just Xdebug and PHPStorm on the background.